# Success / error handler with read/create odata without batch Sapui5

Tags: callback, odata, sapui5, handler

is there any way of triggering a odata create callback , without batch request?
i use this code, but aparently it doesnt work because the odata cant handle batch request.

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("model1").create("/entity", updateEntry , {   
    success: function() {   
        sap.m.MessageBox.success("Registered.", {
            title: "success",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    },
    error: function() {   
        sap.m.MessageBox.error("Error ", {
            title: "Error",                                      
            initialFocus: null                                   
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("model1").setUseBatch(false);`

Comment: Sorry maybe i didnt explain correctly. What would be the alternative way do handle a error success callback with create. Supposedly my code is only valid for a odatathat supports batch request. I set use batch false in the manifest.json

Comment: im not sure what youre trying to ask to be honest, but your code should also work for an odata endpoint that does not support batch.

Comment: in that case, the odata isnt formed correctly, its a custom odata formed with olingo libraries. In other cases it worked perfectly .. but with this case it didnt... i just dont get any response. Thanks anyway!